# NoClassDefFoundError Java-Memory-Manipulation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory-management, jna

I'm trying to edit the memory of another program. I'm trying to use IntelliJ idea to do it. So I've added the Java-Memory-Manipulation library and it's dependencies as Libraries in the IntelliJ project. And it compiles. and gives me a jar with all of the library files contained inside it. But when I try to run it it fails with NoClassDefFoundError on a class from JavaMemoryManipulation. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Note these are seperate class files.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        processLoader processLoader = new processLoader();
        System.out.println(processLoader.csgo.toString());

    }
}

public final class processLoader {
    Process csgo;
    {

         csgo = Processes.byName("csgo_linux64");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide the complete error details

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jonatino/process/Processes
 at com.crazilyfingerme.valarium.processLoader.<clinit>(processLoader.java:10)
 at com.crazilyfingerme.valarium.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.jonatino.process.Processes
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 2 more

Comment: Check this link, you have to download the appropriate library for your OS. https://processing.org/download/

Comment: What does processing have to do with anything? I'm using intelliJ rn.

Comment: What is the os are you using now ?

Comment: Fedora 30 64 bit

Comment: Check this link and use the right version.https://github.com/Jonatino/Java-Memory-Manipulation